# What color space to use for EXR in textures

Tags: texturing, image, color-management, hdri

I've searched high and low for this, and cannot find an answer anywhere, even in the new 2.80 docs.

When you import import or environment textures in 2.80, the new texture node has several colour space options:

- xyz
- sRGB
- Raw
- Non-color
- Linear ACES
- Linear
- Filmic Log

What do they do, and what one SHOULD be used for EXR files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For EXR use Linear.

(If you know that your EXRs are encoded using other color space... then you would know the answer already)

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on why we should use linear and not raw as data is not transformed before being saved into the exr ? Thanks !